# how is the support for latest VS2022 for c++22std?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, c++20

This built and executed with GCC 11.2, yet does not compile with VS2022 C++.

```
#include <concepts>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

// bit_width including the sign-bit
template < std::integral N > consteval 
std::size_t bit_width(N = {}) noexcept
```

with the error,

```
Reverse.cpp(6): Error E0135: namespace "std" has no member "integral"
```

It works with GCC.

Comment: There's a table at cppreference.com, note gcc is ahead of other compilers. Standardization of C++23 has just begun, so you shouldn't expect too much.

Comment: `std::integral` is from C++20. [Works for me](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Tqd8Tr98n), did you enable C++20 support?

Comment: I only have VS2019 installed, but I do know if you want the latest C++ standard enabled, you have to go into project property settings to set it to the latest.  Click the Project menu option and select Properties. From the dialog that appears, drill into C/C++ -> Language and look for "C++ Language Standard".

Comment: Thank you for catching that HolyBlackCat, I meant to say c++20, not c++22. I found the project menu option and it now compiles and executes perfectly. The UI for VS22 has much improved!